# Allow Cross Domain Sharing on Node

Tags: node.js

How do I allow cross domain sharing using only the http module on node.  I don't want to use express or any other framework.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this bit of code](https://gist.github.com/balupton/3696140) that outputs CORS headers using the http module.